# Game freezes when returning an integer?

Tags: java, int, game-engine, slick2d

I'm having a really strange problem in the java game I'm developing in slick2d.
It is a 2d shooter with zombies and a hero character who can shoot them
Whenever I add numerous zombies and fire bullets it freezes.

This is the code where I'm having the problem:

```
    String ammoLevel = "";
    if(heroData.getAmmo() > 100){
        ammoLevel = "High";
    }else if(heroData.getAmmo() > 60){
        ammoLevel = "Medium";       
    }else{
        ammoLevel = "Low";
    }



behaviour = tree.getBehaviour(heroData .getZombiesExist(),
            ammoLevel, calculate(heroData.getHealth()),
            inCover, nearEnemies, calculateAmmo(tm.getAmmo()), networkOutput);
```

With the ammoLevel being the problem.

For some reason when I get the heroData.getAmmo() value back

```
 public int getAmmo(){
    return heroAmmo;
}
```

and its below a certain value the whole game freezes?

Initially the ammo is set to 100 and I just decrement it by one, everytime the hero shoots.

Has anybody had any wierd problems like this before - or know a good way to debug it? Thanks for any help!

Comment: We have way to few code to tell you what the problem is. Give us at least `calculateAmmo`. You might be stuck in an infinite loop. Or the behavior tree has a dead end.

Comment: I'm not using calculateAmmo for the heroAmmo though - it is simply the code above where it sets a string for 'ammoLevel'

Comment: What is the tm.getAmmo() function, what is tm? I don't see the initialization of the object?

Comment: Is it a particular number that it freezes at, like 0, or as soon as it's < 60?  Are you sure it's freezing on the `getAmmo()` and not in processing later when `ammoLevel` is 'Low'?  I would suggest putting in some `println()` statements in to find the exact line where it's freezing.

Comment: @matt: The String algo isn't the problem. That piece of code is fine.

Comment: Okay thanks for all your help - and martijin for pushing me in the direction of the behaviour tree - for some reason its not liking the value "Medium".

Comment: Just to note: as soon as you want to label something "weird" or "strange" - hit yourself on the head with a rolled up newspaper. Bad! Bad! It is not productive to want something to be strange, you want it to be something stupid and sensible that you're simply overlooking. Then all you have to do is find the problem and fix it - a different (open) mindset that makes things a whole lot easier in the end.

Comment: Hah you were right Gimby , I'll try and remember this. Bascially in my tree class I was getting stuck in an infinite loop - such a basic error - thanks everyone for nudging me in the right direction!

Comment: @matt Can you post the answer and mark it as the solution?